# Storing sensitive information in git/travis workflows

Tags: github, deployment, travis-ci

I am using Github as the repository for a package I am building. At the moment I have a `.travis.yml` file setup that helps with automatically testing the code as it is pushed in. Eventually I'd like to deploy the package to a service like [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org)) but the language and package manager a re unimportant to the question).

[Reading the documentation shows that its relatively easy to do this automatically:](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/pypi/)

> For a minimal configuration, all you need to do is add the following
>   to your .travis.yml:
>
> ```
> deploy:
>   provider: pypi
>   user: "Your username"
>   password: "Your password"
> ```

Except for the relatively small hitch that ***I'd need to put the username and password for PyPI into a publically visible yaml file***.

Obviously this is bad practice, and I'm sure there are ways around this via tokens or something, but googling shows [lots of suggestions](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html) [along the same lines](https://github.com/mrtazz/simplenote.py/blob/master/.travis.yml) of "put your password here".

Am I missing something here? Or are people just putting their authentication keys into publicly visible files?

Answer (score 2):

If you [search GitHub for password `.pypirc`](https://github.com/search?q=password%20.pypirc&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) or [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=password%20.travis.yml&type=Code&ref=searchresults), you would find actually many scripts for *generating* the `.pypirc` (for example) file.

The main idea is to version a `.travis.yml` *template* and use the deploy process to replace the placeholder values (like password: @password@) with the actual password which should *not* be stored in a git repo.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But how does that password get filled in? I mean, if I do an automatic push to Github `->` TravisCI `->` PyPI, where do I store or how do I enter, the password?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr good question. I mainly see http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Secure-Variables, which isn't exactly the same as my answer.